# What control should i use to display an image saved in database and encoded as Image

Tags: asp.net, .net

All is in the question.
I have an image saved in database in an Image column. How could i manage to display it in an aspx page ?

The problem is i don't know how to display an image without specifing an Url.
Thanks in advance for your help
Have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with an HTTP Handler serving the image while referencing that handler in an html image tag.

Take a look at [this](http://aspalliance.com/1322_Displaying_Images_in_ASPNET_Using_HttpHandlers.1) article for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Write a handler that returns the specific image based an URL parameters (writing the byte array of the image into the response) and set that as the URL of the Image control.

Answer (score 0):

Create a HTTP handler and called the handler in the in every img scr

```
<img src="ShowImg.ashx?ID=imageid" alt="imgetitle" />
```

handler will load the image from the imageid passed as a querystring to it. on handler we will right the code to read the image from database and display on the page.